# Is There a Markdown Syntax for Titles, Author, Etc?

Tags: markdown

I just saw a video on Markdown which uses a percent sign (%) to add a title and author to a document.  Here is the video clip (strating from the relevant section):  https://youtu.be/hpAJMSS8pvs?t=5m30s

I have not been able to reproduce this feature, though (I've tried in different markdown editors -- like StackEdit).

Is this a different version of Markdown?  Do I just need a different editor?

In short, any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Markdown metadata format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215896/markdown-metadata-format)

Answer (score 25):

Yes, some markdown engines support this using [metadata blocks](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#metadata-blocks).

The following is called [yaml_metadata_block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) by pandoc (this format is supported by Jekyll, StackEdit and quite a few others):

```
---
title: my title
author: my name
date: today
---
```

or equivalently:

```
---
title: my title
author: my name
date: today
...
```

---

Pandoc also supports the `pandoc_title_block` format:

```
% title
% author(s) (separated by semicolons)
% date
```

Comment: I favour the `Yaml` block notation to the `pandoc` notation as you see in each line where you are (e.g. `title: ...` and not just `% super titlename`)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such standard syntax for Title or Author.
But you can always mention them below your first Heading.

I prefer in this way

#### HEADING - I

---

### **Title** - Documentation 
**Author** - Saumitra Jagdale 
**Created On** - 2 October 2020