# writing markdown for gridsome. Is array of objects possible?

Tags: vue.js, markdown, gridsome

I'm using a website with Gridsome and I use markdown files to feed content to the website.

I have little experience with markdown. While I don't really understand how md files work, I managed to get it working with a few tutorials until I started adding arrays into the md file see below.

```
content/home/index.md

---
metaTitle: this is the meta title tag
metaDescription: metadescription
someArray: [alpha, beta, delta] //I tried adding an array like this and it worked fine
imgArray: [{url: "someurl", alt: "some alt", caption: "some caption}, {url: "someurl", alt: "some alt", caption: "some caption}] //this did not work and caused an error
---
```

my question is whether adding an array of objects in markdown files possible? if it is, how do I write it? thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your YAML, the array is invalid in that it's missing quotes after `some caption`.

---

The section of metadata you're describing is the *[YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215896/markdown-metadata-format) frontmatter*, and it's not specific to Gridsome or Vue.

Yes, object arrays are allowed in YAML either as comma-separated objects:

```yaml
imgArray2: [
 {url: "someurl", alt: "some alt", caption: "some caption"},
 {url: "someurl", alt: "some alt", caption: "some caption"}
]
```

[demo](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=someArray%3A+%5Balpha%2C+beta%2C+delta%5D%0AimgArray2%3A+%5B%0A+%7Burl%3A+%22someurl%22%2C+alt%3A+%22some+alt%22%2C+caption%3A+%22some+caption%22%7D%2C%0A+%7Burl%3A+%22someurl%22%2C+alt%3A+%22some+alt%22%2C+caption%3A+%22some+caption%22%7D%0A%5D&type=json)

...or as lists, where each element starts on a new line with a hyphen prefix:

```yaml
imgArray:
 - {url: "someurl", alt: "some alt", caption: "some caption"}
 - {url: "someurl", alt: "some alt", caption: "some caption"}
```

[demo](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=someArray%3A+%5Balpha%2C+beta%2C+delta%5D%0AimgArray%3A%0A+-+%7Burl%3A+%22someurl%22%2C+alt%3A+%22some+alt%22%2C+caption%3A+%22some+caption%22%7D%0A+-+%7Burl%3A+%22someurl%22%2C+alt%3A+%22some+alt%22%2C+caption%3A+%22some+caption%22%7D&type=json)

Comment: thank you! your solution worked. I didnt forget the closing quote in my code but I tried again and it worked.